# Expanding rows in Excel

Tags: excel, dax, powerquery

There is probably a simple solution to this, but I've been banging my head against a wall. I have about two hundred rows where the first five columns are the same and the final column has a number. I want to expand the table to have x amount of duplicate rows. X being the number in the final column. I thought I could unpivot, but that doesn't seem to be working. Any solutions I'm unaware of?  For example:

```
Row 1.  a   b   c   5 <br>
Row 2  aa   bb  cc  3
```

Becomes:

```
a   b   c
a   b   c
a   b   c
a   b   c
a   b   c

aa  bb  cc
aa  bb  cc
aa  bb  cc
```

Comment: It looks like the first "three" columns are the same (not five). Please confirm.

Comment: I don't see **any** columns the same as any others, never mind 5 of them.

Comment: Sorry, hastily and poorly written. I only used three columns in the example, but the actual sheet has 6 total columns. As in the example above, I want to take values in the first five columns and make duplicate rows to equal the number in the final column. So if the values in row 1 are a,b,c,d,e,5, I would end up with 5 total rows of a,b,c,d,e. If row 2 is aa,bb,cc,dd,ee, 3, I will end up with three rows of aa,bb,cc,dd,ee. Ihave roughly 500 rows that I need to expand to 6000, so I don't want to do it manually. I can write the VBA, but if there is an easier dax solution it will save me time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Power Query (Get & Transform Data).

- Ensure your source data is formatted as a table.
- Change "Table1" and "Column6" names to suit your data.

  ```
  let
      Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
      #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column6", Int64.Type}}),
      #"List Numbers" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Changed Type", {"Column6", each List.Numbers(1,_,1), type list}),
      #"Expanded Rows" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"List Numbers", "Column6")
  in
      #"Expanded Rows"
  ```

Note that this is M (Power Query language), not DAX.

Comment: Thanks, Olly.  This is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a simple macro. You can see sample macro VB code below.

```
Sub Create()

Dim count As Integer
Dim col1 As String       
Dim col2 As String
Dim col3 As String

Dim row_counter As Integer

row_counter = 1

For x = 1 To 2

    count = Sheet1.Cells(x, "D")
    col1 = Sheet1.Cells(x, "A")
    col2 = Sheet1.Cells(x, "B")
    col3 = Sheet1.Cells(x, "C")

    For y = 1 To count

        Sheet2.Cells(row_counter, "A") = col1
        Sheet2.Cells(row_counter, "B") = col2
        Sheet2.Cells(row_counter, "C") = col3
        row_counter = row_counter + 1

    Next y
Next x
End Sub
```